# Working of assignment operator while copying objects

Tags: c++, operators, variable-assignment

The assignment operator copies one object to another member-wise. If you do not overload the assignment operator, it performs the bitwise copy.
When the bitwise assignment is performed both the object shares the same memory location and changes in one object reflect in another object.
This concept and my code goes contrary. Can someone please explain me why..

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
        int x;
};

int main()
{
    A a1,a2;
    a1.x=5;
    a2.x=5;
    a2=a1;
    a1.x=10;
    cout<<a1.x<<" "<<a2.x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"If you do not overload the assignment operator, it performs the bitwise copy"* Wrong. It assigns each member, which for scalar types might mean bitwise copy, but for classes it invokes their assignment operators. And even for scalars, a "bitwise copy" doesn't mean sharing the same memory. It means *copying* bits to another location.

Comment: `a2 = a1` does not make the two objects share the same memory location in C++. In some other languages (e.g. Java), where we have reference semantics, that assignment would make both variables refer to the same object -- that's not what C++ does.

Comment: Your code does not back up your understanding, therefore your understanding is wrong. In particular copying is copying, not sharing, and bitwise is not memberwise. The default assignment operator is memberwise copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the bitwise assignment is performed both the object shares the same memory location and changes in one object reflect in another object.

This is incorrect. Bitwise copy assignment does not lead to objects sharing the same memory. It's a separate copy, so `a2` and `a1` are in fact in different memory location.

> This concept and my code goes contrary.

You probably got mixed up with the case where copy assignment is done with a pointer member variable. In that case, indeed the default bitwise assignment would lead to objects having pointers pointing to the same memory, and requires `deep` copy assignment instead (of the default assignment).

Your current code does not have any pointer member though, so such deep copy is not required.

Comment: okay thanks this is clear..But I am still confused with default copy constructor and assignment operator. Is there any difference in the working of them.

Comment: @PriyaPatni the way you wrote it `a2=a1;` was assignment. The default copy constructor would be something like this: `A a2(a1);` , so you declared `a2` object using the default copy constructor, with `a1` is the object being used to copy to `a2`.

Comment: my question is - whether in both the cases (i.e. Default copy constructor and assignment operator) separate memory is allocated for objects

Comment: @PriyaPatni the short answer is - yes, the two objects will have separate memory in both cases. The longer answer is - 1. Technically, neither copy constructors nor assignment operators allocate memory (allocation is handled by things like function prologues and new operators) - 2. If two object each contain a member pointer, the pointers themselves will have separate memory, but they can both _point_to_ the same memory. There are "tricks" (like "placement new") that allow you to override normal behaviour. - 3. References that are members of objects work much like member pointers do.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a pointer in your class since two object the origin and assigned object access to same memory address so if you change this memory location the modification is visible for two objects.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class A
{
   public:
     int x;
     int *y;
};

int main()
{
 A a1,a2;
 a1.x=5;
 a1.y = new int(7);
 a2.x=5;
 a2=a1;
 a1.x=10;
 *a2.y = 9;
 cout<<a1.x<<" "<<a2.x;
 cout<<*a1.y<<" "<<*a2.y; // the output is 9 9/ because both object access two same memory address
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The values of *a1* are copied in *a2*. If your class had pointer, then the pointer value, ie the address would be copied the same, which would mean that had be sharing same address and then changing value in one is changing value in the other as well.

Answer (score 0):

> When the bitwise assignment is performed both the object shares the same memory location and changes in one object reflect in another object.

is wrong. Copying is copying. This means data in the memory location for source object is **copied** to another memory location for destination object. No memory location sharing is done.

Answer (score 0):

You understanding of default assignment operators is incorrect, default assignment operators use a copying method known as a member-wise copy. I will not share the memory.

Since, you misunderstood the concept, there is an expected behavior.